# How to make Keycloak automatically redirect to login page if request fails

Tags: openid-connect, keycloak, keycloak-services, mod-auth-openidc

I have an `Keycloak` server and using `mod_auth` on Apache to manage the request.

Currently, in my client application, when I face with a `401` request, I trigger an location.reload() and thus being redirected to `Keycloak` logging page. But this feel very unnatural.

I want to ask if there is  another, office way that do the redirecting automatically from `Keycloak` side/server side?

//////Edited////

I use mod_auth_openidc for Apache, which mean there is no adapter on client-side

Keyckoak version:4.4.0

Comment: Which keycloak version do you use? Which adapter do you work with? Sending that kind of redirections works out of the box in Spring Security and Spring Boot adapters.

Comment: @XtremeBiker: Added additional information.

Comment: Okey, then you might need to configure that module in some way that sends a redirect when a 401 error happens (you probably would like to do it for browser requests, meaning web page requests and not the REST API, if you have one).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `OIDCUnAuthAction` to configure the action to be taken on an incoming unauthenticated request, see:
https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/blob/v2.3.8/auth_openidc.conf#L697

This is a per-path/location/directory setting, so in your case you'd configure:

```
OIDCUnAuthAction auth
```

on that specific path.